# Populate an ArrayList of different instances of a class

Tags: java, android, json

First of all, here is an overview of my application. I want to create a multiple-choice app, on android, using data stored on a remote MySQL database. The DB has 100 questions that will appear in random order.

My php script returns a JSON array with the following results

```
[
 {
    "id": 1,
    "Question": " blahblahblahblahblah?"
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "Question": "blehblehblehblehblehblehblehblehbleh?"
},
]
```

Since the Question table on my database has integers and strings I thought that it would be a better approach to copy the information of the JSON Objects to different instances of a Class Question. I want the JSONArray to be created once in order to avoid multiple requests to the server.That's why I wrote the following code:

```
public class Question {
    int question_id;
    String question_txt ;
    JSONArray json ;


public int setQuestion_id(int i) {
    try {this.question_id = this.json.getJSONObject(i).getInt("id");}
    catch (JSONException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

    return question_id;
}

public String setQuestion_txt(int i) {
    try {this.question_txt=this.json.getJSONObject(i).getString("Question");} 
    catch (JSONException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

    return question_txt;
}

public JSONArray setJson()throws JSONException, IOException {
    java.net.HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    URL url = new URL("url_to_my.php");
    connection = (java.net.HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-length", "0");
    connection.setUseCaches(false);
    connection.setConnectTimeout(0);
    connection.setReadTimeout(0);
    connection.connect();
    int status = connection.getResponseCode();
    JSONArray json = null;


    switch (status) {
        case 200:
        case 201:

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line;

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }

            this.json = new JSONArray(sb.toString());
            br.close();
    }
    return this.json;

}

}
```

What I tried doing is creating an ArrayList questionnaire and add to it different instances of the Class Question with different values.

```
ArrayList<Question> questionnaire = new ArrayList<Question>();
Question q = new Question();    

for(int i=0; i< q.setJson().length() ;i++){
    Question newQuestion = new Question();
             newQuestion.json = q.json;
             newQuestion.setQuestion_id(i);
             newQuestion.setQuestion_txt(i);
             questionnaire.add(newQuestion);}
```

Everything seems to work fine, at least for now. Later on, I want the JSON result to return more information like the possible answers and which is the correct one.

Comment: I have rolled back your last edit. Please don't change or add to the code in your question after you have received answers. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good effort to get your code working so far. But your code is highly unusual.

You've got the class `Question` which has an `id` and `question_txt`, but each `Question` also has a reference to a JSONArray of all the questions. Worse than that, for each `Question`, when you create a new Question and set its reference to all questions, it will come from the API each time.

You've recognised that the behaviour of getting `Question`s from the API might belong in the `Question` class (or related class), instead of forcing `main` (or whatever consumer) to know the details of the API. But it's surely not the responsibility of a single `Question` instance to fetch all the `Question`s.

You want the class `Question` to hold it's data first (and later, some behaviour), so here's a typical data class.

```java
public class Question {

    private int id;
    private String text;

    public Question (int i, String s) {
        this.id = i;
        this.text = s;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text; 
    }

}
```

You'll see this type of class referred to  as Java Bean or POJO. In this case, because we've used `private` and only provided `get` methods, this is a read-only object after its been created.

Then add some behaviour to the *class* (meaning we're going to use the `static` keyword) for retrieving the questions:

```java
public static List<Question> fetchQuestions () throws JSONException, IOException {

    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("url_to_my.php").openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-length", "0");
    connection.setUseCaches(false);
    connection.setConnectTimeout(0);
    connection.setReadTimeout(0);
    connection.connect();
    int status = connection.getResponseCode();
    if (!(status == 200 || status == 201)) {
        throw new IOException("Bad status code: " + status);
    }

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line + "\n");
    }
    br.close();
    String response = sb.toString();

    List<Question> questions = new ArrayList<Question>();
    for (Object arrayItem: new JSONArray(response)) {
        JSONObject questionAsJSON = (JSONObject) arrayItem; // throws on unexpected response format
        questions.add(new Question(questionAsJSON.getInt("id"), 
                questionAsJSON.getString("Question")));
    }

    return questions;

}
```

And then when we want to grab the questions from the API, it's just a case of invoking the static method:

```java
List<Question> questionnaire = Question.fetchQuestions();
```

Comment: Hi Jeremy, it seems like you can't iterate with for each loop a JSONArray. Therefore I made some modifications to your code (Check my Edit). Other than that, your code is what I wanted to do from the beginning, but I couldn't figure how.

Comment: `JSONArray` is `Iterable` for me. Could be a version difference? I'm using `<dependency>groupId>org.json</groupId><artifactId>json</artifactId><version>20190722</version></dependency>`